# App giving continuous warning : could not load any Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my app in several places where I've used Objective-C classes the App is giving the following warning.  Its making the late exection of the code.  What is this warning? Why is it coming?

Warning is:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

My app is written in Swift and I've included some Objective-C files.
I've included the `SDWebCache` third party library which is written in Objective-C for lazy loading of images from the server.